# "Cannot find bounds of current function" error in GDB while debugging bootloader code

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev, gnu-assembler

I'm currently learning bootloader development and debugging with GDB to observe memory changes when the A20 line is disabled in real mode. Since QEMU automatically enables the A20 line, I'm attempting to disable it using the `int 15` interrupt. I have a bootloader (boot.S) that I'm trying to debug using GDB.

I've set up my debugging environment in `.gdbinit` followed by `make debug` to launch GDB. However, when I try to step through my code, I encounter the error "Cannot find bounds of current function". This particularly occurs after executing the `int` instruction at line number 18 (boot.S).

I know I am doing something wrong here(my assembly code skills are still developing), but I don't know what it is :(

boot.S

```
BOOT_SIGNATURE = 0xAA55
A20_TEST_VALUE = 0x3773

ES_EDGE_ADDR   = 0xFFFF
ES_OFFSET_ADDR = 0x0010

.code16
.global start
start:
    xorw %ax, %ax
    cli
    cld
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %ss
    movw %ax, %es

movw $0x2400, %ax
int $0x10

call check_a20_status
jmp .

check_a20_status:
    xorw %ax, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es
    movw %ax, %cx
    movw $ES_EDGE_ADDR, %ax
    movw $ES_OFFSET_ADDR, %bx
    movw %ax, %es
    movw $A20_TEST_VALUE, %es:(%bx)
    movw %ds:0x0, %ax

    ret

signature_padding:
    .space 510 - (. - start)
    .word  BOOT_SIGNATURE
```

Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -nostartfiles -nostdlib -m32 -e start -g
LFLAGS = -Wl,-Ttext=0x7c00 -Wl,--build-id=none -Wl,--oformat=binary
BOOT_BIN = -o boot.bin
BOOT_SRC = boot.S
GDB_PORT=3773

obj:
    gcc -nostartfiles -nostdlib -m32 -e start -g -Wl,-Ttext=0x7c00 -o boot.out boot.S
    
image: obj
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(BOOT_BIN) $(BOOT_SRC)
    
debug: image
    qemu-system-i386 -drive file=boot.bin,format=raw -nographic -serial mon:stdio -gdb tcp::$(GDB_PORT) -S
    
gdb:
    gdb -n -x .gdbinit

clean:
    rm -rf *.bin *.out
```

.gdbinit

```
set architecture i8086
target remote localhost:3773
symbol-file boot.out
```

I launched qemu using the command `make debug` in one terminal and then started the gdb in another terminal using the command `make gdb`. I have attached the screenshot of gdb output here[image]

Any insights, or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use the instruction stepping commands `ni` and `si` instead.

Comment: `movw $0x2400, %ax` / `int $0x10` what is this service?

Comment: You can also use `layout asm` to get disassembly of the machine code that's actually there, rather than just lines from the source file.

Comment: @Jester Yes I tried and it not showing the message when using `ni`. But it just going to a loop like I mean I can't get to the instruction after `int $0x15` which is `call check_a20_status`

Comment: If all else fails then put a temporary breakpoint on that `call` and just let the program continue.

Comment: @AbhijithEa It is frowned upon if you change the question so it incorporates info from the answer(s). Doing that tends to invalidate the answer(s). That's why I did a rollback just now. If you need to add extra stuff to your question, then make it stand out clearly by adding the new stuff near the bottom of the post, preferably below a header like **EDIT:**.

Answer (score 2):

### Wrong service

> ```
> movw $0x2400, %ax
> int $0x10
> ```

You want the 'Disable A20 Gate' service at `int 15h`. You have erroneously invoked the video BIOS service interrupt `int 10h`.

### Missing SP

> ```
> xorw %ax, %ax
> cli
> cld
> movw %ax, %ds
> movw %ax, %ss
> movw %ax, %es
> ```

If you're going to change the SS segment register, then also setup the SP stack pointer. Suppose SS:SP was valid before and SP held a small number, then omitting initializing SP (like you are doing) would make SS:SP point to within the Interrupt Vector Table. Any further use of the stack (through `int`, ...) would begin destroying interrupt vectors!

### Solution

```
cld
xorw %ax, %ax
movw %ax, %ds
movw %ax, %es
movw %ax, %ss       <<<<< To be kept close together
movw $0x7C00, %sp   <<<<<  and in this particular order!

movw $0x2400, %ax
int  $0x15
```

Comment: Hi I tried the solution but I still can't get though the debug issue I am having. It still showing `Cannot find bounds of current function` when using the command `n` at the instruction ` int  $0x15`

Comment: @AbhijithEa Does the BIOS in qemu even support that `AX=2400h INT 15h` service? Have you tried omitting the `int $0x15` instruction so as to verify that the `call check_a20_status` runs fine? An interesting read for you could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516531/how-to-unset-a-bit-thereby-closing-the-a20-line?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C65.5030 where there is code for an alternative and safer way to disable A20.

Comment: @AbhijithEa I have edited my answer. Please read the comment about keeping changes to SS and SP close together.